# Android Facebook-Connect button needs to be clicked two times

Tags: java, android

since hours I am trying to figure out why my facebook-connect is not working properly. I always have to click it two times.. the first time I click it I see that the facbeook dialog is opening but its not calling any kind of callback so my Login-Activity is just "resuming".

```
public void onClick_fbIcon(View v) {
    if(!buttonsEnabled)
        return;

    buttonsEnabled = false;
    tryFacebookConnect();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void tryFacebookConnect() {
    Log.d("debug", "start fbc");
    doingFacebooklogin = true;
    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            end();
            toast("Complete");
            Log.d("debug", "#0");   
            // .. continue with main code
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            end();
            Log.d("debug", "#1");           
        }

        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            end();
            Log.d("debug", "#2");
        } 

        public void onCancel() {
            end();
            Log.d("debug", "#3");
        }

        private void end() {
            Log.d("debug", "fbc complete");
            doingFacebooklogin = false;
        }
    });
}
```

The first click I only get "start fbc" but nothing after that, so I guess that no callback method is called.

I found out that when the facebook-connect is not working the first time, "onResume is called". The next time onActivityResult is called.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("debug", "Main: onActivityResult");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

My login activity is an intent started by my main activity that is specifing if a login is needed at all:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Sometimes I can see the following error:

```
11-22 10:23:39.684: D/Facebook-publish(7317): Can NOT get FbInjector instance! Probably because this method was called in ContentProvider's onCreate.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but the problem is obviously part of the facebook-sdk. I found out that this problem does not occur if I have no facebook-app installed on my device. So I changed my code like this:

```
facebook.authorize(a, new String[] { }, **Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH**, new DialogListener() {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this Tutorial. I just Follow this and I make it all works perfectly.

Hope that it will help you too.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xndi6s9Tn_U

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt change anything for me.